# change color to rgb in c# unity

Tags: unity, c#, color

So I am trying to change my color of my sprite to a rgb color. Now I can just change it to a color like red, black or blue...

```
 m_spriteRenderer.color = Color.blue;
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the color you want to the constructor of the [Color object](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color-ctor.html).

Here is a copy of the documentation's example:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        Color newColor = new Color(0.3f, 0.4f, 0.6f);
    }
}
```

You can also use it like that:

```
Color newColor = new Color(0.3f, 0.4f, 0.6f);
m_spriteRenderer.color = newColor;
```

You can see an example of how it can be used in the documentation of the [SpriteRenderer.color](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SpriteRenderer-color.html) function.

Comment: If you find it easier to think of colours in byte values, you can use `new Color32(127, 63, 0xFF)`. These 32-bit colours will implicitly convert to and from the floating point color type, so you can use whichever is clearest for your needs.